# Java Spring Required request body is missing

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am sending HTTP DELETE in the body of the HTTP request:

```
{
    "TaskDTO": [
        {
            "taskid": "31C3C17E80DD41DEB5938E828CDC28EF",
            "refId": null,
            "taskCode": null,
            "taskName": null,
            "status": null,
            "state": null,
            "categories": null,
            "begintime": null,
            "intervals": 60,
            "description": "desc",
            "beanclassname": "Monitor",
            "beanmethodname": "executeReceiveDataTask",
            "beanmethodparams": null,
            "createtime": null,
            "lastupdatetime": null
        }
    ]
}
```

and in my Controller is

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("admin/task")
public class AdminTaskAction {

   @DeleteMapping(value = "")
    public @ResponseBody String delete(@RequestBody List<TaskDTO> taskDTOs){
        ...
    }
}
```

and my TaskDTO is

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TaskDTO implements Serializable {

    private String taskid;

    private String refId;

    private String taskCode;

    private String taskName;

    private String taskCategory;

    private String taskStatus;

    private String state;

    private String description;

    private String categories;

    private Long intervals;

    private String begintime;

    private String beanclassname;

    private String beanmethodname;

    private String beanmethodparams;

    private String createtime;

    private Long lastupdatetime;
}
```

But I am getting

> Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing

Can someone tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Try sending only the list; i.e. from [ to ]

Comment: why not just send the id on the delete method and do a ```taskRepository.deleteById(idFromFrontEnd)```

Answer (score 1):

You should just send the list:

```
[
    {
        "taskid": "31C3C17E80DD41DEB5938E828CDC28EF",
        "refId": null,
        "taskCode": null,
        "taskName": null,
        "status": null,
        "state": null,
        "categories": null,
        "begintime": null,
        "intervals": 60,
        "description": "desc",
        "beanclassname": "Monitor",
        "beanmethodname": "executeReceiveDataTask",
        "beanmethodparams": null,
        "createtime": null,
        "lastupdatetime": null
    }
]
```

Your current JSON expects to be deserialized to a class with a single field named TaskDTO; i.e. something like:

```
public class Dummy {

    private List<TaskDTO> TaskDTO;

    // getters, setters

}
```

Comment: Tried sending the list. Still the same error. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Not all servers supports delete with body. Try post.